# Can I create a document library using SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I need to create a doc library with nested fields on demand (on item creation) 
Can I use SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow?

Comment: Anyone know a function in rest api that can do that on a work flow..? 
(cant buy any tools...)

Comment: A search for "SharePoint rest create list" goes straight to the MSDN example for creating a list using REST: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/offic/dn292552.aspx#WorkLists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a third party tool available which can helps you to create New document library from the workflow.

Please check below link.

[Create List or Library](https://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/docs/administration/)